# Using mysqldump on RDS to export a large file in TSV format

Tags: mysqldump

I would like to export a single, large table (30GB) from an RDS MySQL server on a regular basis into a TSV file, so that we can load the file into Vertica.

However, RDS doesn't provide a way to use mysqldump with the --tab=path option, so we need to parse/convert the INSERT statements to TAB seperated files.

I would like to convert lines from the dump file like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTAble VALUES ('data_1','data_2', 'date_3');
```

to this
    'data_1'   'data_2'     'data_3'

Since I need to parse through a 30G file, I would like to find the most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you need to load 30G each time, or could you either detect deltas or parse binary logs and apply DML?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming RDS with MySQL 5.6 is being used, [mydumper](https://launchpad.net/mydumper) may be a better option. The newer versions [have the RDS grants limitation into account](http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/09/26/logical-mysql-backup-tool-mydumper-0-6-2-now-available/) and you will get all the advantages of mydumper over mysqldump (compression, parallel execution, overall faster speed, etc).

This wouldn't provide TSV data, but by using the `--chunk-filesize` option you can split the data into multiple files in parallel and then process them in parallel afterwards

```
option:: --chunk-filesize -F Split tables into chunks of this output file size. This value is in MB
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, RDS doesn't provide a way to use mysqldump with the --tab=path option, so we need to parse/convert the INSERT statements to TAB seperated files

Try the [mysqltotsv](https://pypi.org/project/mysqltotsv/) pypi module:

```
pip3 install --user mysqltotsv
python3 mysql-to-tsv.py --file dump.sql --outdir out1
```

This will produce multiple `.tsv` files in the `out1` directory (one `.tsv` file for each table found in the MySQL dump).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Unix of some sort, I would use [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html).

Using your data

> INSERT INTO MyTAble VALUES ('data_1','data_2', 'date_3');

and putting this line into a file called testfile.

Run this

```
sed -i s/"INSERT INTO MyTAble VALUES ("//g testfile
```

sed -i is inplace.

```
more testfile
'data_1','data_2', 'date_3');
```

Then

```
sed -i s/);//g testfile 
sed -i s/,//g testfile
```

And then voila!

```
more testfile
'data_1''data_2' 'date_3'
```

So, there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you table has a date field (with an index), I would use:

```
select * from table into OUTFILE 'filename' WHERE date between x and y ;
```

I would dump data per year. Allow you to test the export / import with a smaller data set.